# how to call a javascript function on only first page loading only

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript  function "myFunction()" and i need to call this function on First page load only not for all page.

how can i do it.

I will appreciate a lot your help.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best is to store in `localStorage` the fact that you already visited the site (to be precise it's the "origin").

You can put this code in all your pages :

```
<script>
   if (!localStorage['done']) {
       localStorage['done'] = 'yes';
       myFunction();
   }
</script>
```

If you want to show the page again for next session, replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage`.