# How to run javascript only once after every login?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve that after user logs in to my app, I will have to send get request to my servlet, which will respond with servletOutputStream with some sound message like ('Hello User, how are you'). But I want it to be only once, not after the logged user refreshes the page and hears it again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call a javascript function on only first page loading only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742973/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-on-only-first-page-loading-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as a general solution.**

Check if the user already received the message before outputting the message:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('messageSent')) {
    // 1. create the message for the user here

    // 2. make sure user does not get message again
    localStorage.setItem('messageSent', 'true'); // any truthy value
}
```

Clear the localStorage when user logs out:

```
localStorage.removeItem('messageSent');
```

Based off your question, it seems you can even avoid the above solution and just output the message in the login logic (after user gets authenticated and logs in). When the user refreshes the page, it shouldn't show the message because the login logic should not run when the user is already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie after the first run, and check for the presence of the cookie before. The cookie should only last the length of the current session, assuming you want the message to appear the next time they log in. A quick search should reveal how to set cookies in JS.

Comment: This could create unforeseen issues with session length and cookie length if your code is dynamically refreshing or extending session time for extended usage of your app. Do bare in mind that if your cookie doesn't refresh with session, your two time intervals will no longer coincide. Not all code refreshes sessions but many authentication structures do, as you don't want to lock out an authenticated user just because they've been on for 2+ hours, etc.